# RSA soft token usage

Tags: android, iphone, security, encryption, rsa

One of the requirement i have is to use RSA token for security while transmitting the data between mobile client and server. I have no idea how to use it, can you please give some pointers on how to start using RSA tokens while transmitting data between client and server.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to build up an own protocol implementation with RSA, [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) can help you. It's an open source cryptographic toolkit that implements all common crypto algorithms including RSA. It is possible to compile it under iOS, and there is even a tiny Objective C wrapper called [SSCrypto](http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) around it that makes its usage very convenient.

You can also use the CommonCrypto API or the Security framework API that comes with iOS but I find them much-much more complicated than the OpenSSL + SSCrypto combo

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). You will need a server that supports HTTPS (HTTP over SSL), and possibly a client certificate to authenticate your app. Using it is generally not different than regular HTTP: you send a POST/GET request and get a response. The underlying connection will be encrypted transparently.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. My requirement of iPhone app is specific to use RSA encryption as it is already implemented on server side and my iOS project is just an extension of existing web solution. So i can't ask my client to change the implementation on server.

Comment: Then you should ask your client to share the specification with you. IF they are really using their own, non-standard solution, all bets are off. You can never be sure how secure it is, and no one on SO can really help you.